# Can you allow child component to overflow but not increase overall width of the DOM without modifying parent

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to let the abs-element overflow over component but prevent it from adding horizontal scrolling without modifying any CSS outside of component.

HTML

```
<body>
  <div class="parent">
    Without editing parent, is it possible to allow component to overflow but not create cause additional horizontal scrolling
    <div class="component">
      <div class="abs-element">This is a Long Text that should overflow</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.parent {
  padding: 0 80px;
}
.component{
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  justify-content: end;
}
.abs-element{
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;  
  text-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

Code pen
https://codepen.io/petewins/pen/wvOmvdX